# Form on drupal basic page

Tags: php, html, forms, drupal

I have generated a basic page on drupal: site.com/page
With a simple submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

When you press that button, it always redirects to site.com/index.php.
I guess it has something to do with the way that drupal generates the pages?

Is there a work-around?

Comment: What does the form do? Did you hard-code this into a Drupal page, or did you generate the form with a module?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://drupal.org/node/1043838) has lost of resources on creating form in Drupal, and [this page has lots of information on the form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

Both those links will help you.